# Round down to nearest two decimal based on third decimal value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rounding

I need to round up or down to the nearest two decimal values based on the value of the third decimal. Round up if the third decimal is greater than 4. Round down if it's less than or equal to 4.

The below SQL would get me the values of the third decimal value and I am able to round up, but the floor function does not seem to fulfill the requirement of rounding down to the nearest two decimals.

```
SELECT main,DIV1,CASE 
WHEN 
DIV1 > 4
THEN round(main,2)
ELSE
FLOOR(main)
end as result
 FROM (
select 1400/ 3.6735 AS main,abs(1400/ 3.6735) * power(10,3) % 10 as 'abs%10',abs(1400/ 3.6735) * power(10,3) % 10 DIV 1 as DIV1 
UNION
select 1200/ 3.6735 AS main,abs(1200/ 3.6735) * power(10,3) % 10 as 'abs%10',abs(1200/ 3.6735) * power(10,3) % 10 DIV 1 as DIV1 
UNION
select 9000/ 3.6735 AS main,abs(9000/ 3.6735) * power(10,3) % 10 as 'abs%10',abs(9000/ 3.6735) * power(10,3) % 10 DIV 1 as DIV1  )T;
```

The result for the above is,

```
main      DIV1    result
381.1079    7      381.11
326.6639    3      326
2449.9796   9      2449.98
```

The desired result is,

```
main      DIV1    result   desiredResult
381.1079    7      381.11     381.11
326.6639    3      326        326.66
2449.9796   9      2449.98    2449.98
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c32941587d7f27b3f9a24dedb22bb422)

Comment: Bear in mind that SQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else.

Comment: Was a [round](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function too direct in achieving the results?

Comment: *Round up if the third decimal is greater than 4. Round down if it's less than or equal to 4* 1.114 and 1.1149 should both return 1.11? Or should 1.11400000001 return 1.12?

Comment: Why doesn't `round(main,2)` return the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL's `floor` and `ceil` don't take a precision argument like `round` does. But you can emulate this behavior by multiplying the value by 100, flooring it, and then dividing back:

```
CASE 
WHEN 
div1 > 4
THEN CEIL(main * 100.0) / 100.0
ELSE FLOOR(main * 100.0) / 100.0
END
```

Comment: I have done an edit on the desired result but wont the round function do the exact same thing?

Comment: @Bisoux `round` decides for you if it's going to round up or down, based on the digit after the required precision. Since you want to control whether the rounding is done up or down based on the value of `div`, you need to use `ceil` and `floor`.

Comment: The CEIL & FLOOR functions return the result in four decimal places in this case. Applying the round function to the CEIL & FLOOR in this case shouldnt affect the result right ?

Comment: I used the truncate function instead of round